# Codeigniter Table Row Group With Dynamic Table header

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to group row and data will be in single row based on date(table header). Currently I've tried so many way but unsuccessful

check this image to understand more [click here to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86uUm.png)

This my target result : [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItSvb.png)

below are my code so far

CONTROLLER

```
public function index()
    {

        $trkh_d = $this->input->post('trkh_d');
        $trkh_m = $this->input->post('trkh_m'); 
        $trkh_y = $this->input->post('trkh_y');

        $data = array(
            'trkh_m' => $trkh_m,
            'trkh_y' => $trkh_y
        );

        if ($trkh_m == "" || $trkh_y == "") {
            $data['date_range_error_message'] = "Both date fields are required";
        } else {
            $result = $this->timetable_m->show_data_month($data);

            if ($result != false) {
                $data['result_display'] = $result;
            } else {
                $data['result_display'] = "No record found !";
            }
        }

        $this->template->load('tpl_timetable', 'timetable/timetable_form', $data);
```

MODEL

```
public function show_data_month($data) 
    {

        $this->db->select("
            model_name as MODEL,
            material_no as MATERIALNO,
            material_name as MATERIALDESC,
            date_format(start_date, '%d') as STARTDATE,
            target_qty as TARGET");
        $this->db->from('rom_planning');
        $this->db->where('MONTH(start_date)', $data['trkh_m']);
        $this->db->where('YEAR(start_date)', $data['trkh_y']);
        $this->db->order_by('MATERIALDESC');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result_array();
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

VIEW

```
<div class="box-body table-responsive">
          <table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead> 
              <tr>
                <th>NO</th>
                <th>MODEL</th>
                <th>MATERIALNO</th>
                <th>MATERIALDESC</th>
                <?php

                  $trkh_d = "";

                    $tday_month = date("t",mktime(0,0,0,$trkh_m,1,$trkh_y));
                    if ($trkh_d != "") 
                    {
                      $tday_month = $trkh_d;
                      $trkh_start_day = $trkh_d;

                    } else {
                      $tday_month = $tday_month;
                      $trkh_start_day = 1;
                    }

                    for ($t = $trkh_start_day; $t <= $tday_month; $t++) {   

                        echo '<th>'.str_replace('_',' ',strtoupper($t)).'</th>';


                       }  ?>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php $no =1;
              if (isset($result_display)) 
              {
                echo "<p>Result :<b> " . $trkh_m . " - " . $trkh_y . "</b></p>";
                if ($result_display == 'No record found !') {
                echo $result_display;
              } else {
                for ($i=0; $i < count($result_display); $i++) { ?>

                <tr>
                  <td><?=$no++ ?></td>
                  <td><?=$result_display[$i]['MODEL'] ?></td>
                  <td><?=$result_display[$i]['MATERIALNO'] ?></td>
                  <td><?=$result_display[$i]['MATERIALDESC'] ?></td>

                  <?php 

                    for($baris = $trkh_start_day; $baris <= $tday_month; $baris++) {
                      if ($baris == $result_display[$i]['STARTDATE']){
                        echo "<td>". $result_display[$i]['STARTDATE']. "</td>" ;
                      } else {
                        echo "<td>". "-". "</td>" ;
                      }

                      }
                      } ?>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

I hope someone can help me or giving me some idea.

Thank you in advance

Comment: if you need result in group then you need to change layout also

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by changing the layout? that the exact layout i want that table header will be date from 1 to 30/31 vertically so I can see for each day how many output target. appreciated for your comment, thanks

Comment: so if 1 MATERIALNO having 4 record in different time period then it will be displayed 4 rows why u need 1 row

Comment: thank you for your comment, i wanted to organize the table just like timetable and get total sum based on each materialno, i edited above and put my target result. thank you again